# Startcoroutine is not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, coroutine

I'm trying to make a delay between showing two text. But Its is not working.
Code is:

```
public class Class1: MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Text text1, text2;
    public bool inArea = false;

    private void Update () 
    {
       if (!inArea)
       {
           inArea     = true;
           text1.text = "";
           text2.text = "text2";
           StartCoroutine(timer());
           text2.text = "text3";            
      }
 }
 IEnumerator timer()
 {
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(100);
 }
```

I've also tried `WaitForSecondsRealTime()`. It is also not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstood this a bit I think.

A coroutine will run parallel to the other stuff (in your case the `text2.text = "text3"`) if it is not itself delay with a `yield` (for this you need to call your coroutine from a coroutine or use javascript which will do this internally).

You either have to move all your code to the coroutine that should be effected by the delay like this:

```
private void Update () 
{
    if (!inArea)
    {
        inArea = true;
        StartCoroutine(timer());          
    }
}

IEnumerator timer()
{
    text1.text = "";
    text2.text = "text2";

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(100);
    text2.text = "text3";  
}
```

Or you could make `Update` a coroutine too by changing `void Update` to `IEnumerator Update`.

In your current case the first should be fine.

Comment: Many new Unity programmers don't understand what goes on behind coroutines and how it works and that leads to problems like this one...

Comment: Thanks for help. I actually haven't idea of working of coroutine. I searched  about delay and found some of that kind of solutions. Thanks